# Npm Install Strapi to existing NextJS project

Tags: npm, next.js, directory-structure

I'm new to React, NextJS, and Npm, I recently created a `Next` app using this command:
`npx create-next-app@latest`
And now I want to add `Strapi` to the same project. I used this command to install Strapi:
`npx create-strapi-app@latest my-project --quickstart`
Using this command, it will create a new project, for Strapi.
I see that the `Next` and the `Strapi` projects share a lot of files, such as the files in the `node_modules` folder. Is there a way to have those in the same project? or would that make a mess?

Comment: definitely, the best workaround that I wondering about these days. looking forward to the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came to the conclusion that having those two apps on two different directories, with each having their own config files, and other modules, is the right way. We will end up with a lot of files and folders that exist in both apps, but it is simply best that we isolate these two apps from each other completely, because:

- They have different config files, in most of the folders.
- they are two different apps, `Stapi` being the `backend api` and the `admin dashboard`, and the `Nextjs app` being the rest of the website.
- If those two apps were combined, we would end up with a `directory-structure` that would be very hard to work with.

In a larger project we might have more `api` or `apps` that run independently, and it's best to have those on different directories and ports. And having some duplicate files across all the apps, wouldn't affect performance, and wouldn't take much storage.

Comment: Was considering a merge of our Strapi + Web project, but sounds like that would be a recipe for disaster in the long run. Thanks for sharing this answer!